# How to pass WCF credentials in single request?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have this binding:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="b1">
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameForSslNegotiated">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
        </security>
        <binaryMessageEncoding/>
        <httpTransport/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

When I use a sniffer to see the calls, I see that this does 3 round-trips per call.

By looking at the requests I see that

- Message 1 is of type `<t:RequestSecurityToken …>`
- Message 2 is of type `<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse…>`
- Message 3 is the real request

Is there a way pass credentials with the real message?

**UPDATE Aug 23rd 2010:** I still haven't found a solution to this problem.

Comment: if you can't determine what all these round trips are for by looking at the network sniffer output, then how can *we* determine what they are for, _without_ looking at the sniffer output?

Comment: Well, I had the same problem a while back with the wsHttpBinding. With wsHttpBinding, the establishSecurityContext attribute was set to True by default and that caused 3 round-trips per request. Setting establishSecurityContext to False resolved this problem. This time with customBinding, the establishSecurityContext attribute does not exist… So I guess I'm looking for the same attribute but for customBinding. I thought someone might know the answer right away.

Comment: That just sounds like you're not doing any authentication at all now...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using `HTTPS` for your transport, have you tried:

`UserNameOverTransport`, so that the "secure" transport is used to exchange the credentials, rather it trying to set up a "secure" message channel.

Also your `secureConversationBootstrap` is redundant, as it's only used when `authenticationMode="SecureConversation"`

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="b1">
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"/>
        <binaryMessageEncoding/>
        <httpsTransport/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

If you want everything to be in the clear, then use `<httpTransport/>`